# What is the meaning of "to engage in employment"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does "employment" mean employing an employee as an employer or seeking a job as an employee (or could mean both?)

Comment: You could improve this question quite a bit by giving a longer example of where  you've seen this phrase used. Sometimes the larger context determines what words mean. See our [*Details, Please* meta post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) for more question tips.

Answer (score 1):

From U.S.A. immigration forms, [8 CFR §214.1(e)](https://www.nafsa.org/_/file/_/amresource/8cfr2141.htm):

> A nonimmigrant in the United States in a class defined in section 101(a)(15)(B) of the Act as a temporary visitor for pleasure, or section 101(a)(15)(C) of the Act as an alien in transit through this country, may not engage in any employment.

As used here, `engage in employment` means `to be hired as an employee`. The converse would be unacceptable -- consider a temporary resident being unable to hire someone to fix plumbing in his home, or a mover to bring her furniture to a new residence.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and the reference. It does help!

Comment: Glad it helps! Immigration is confusing enough without a language barrier.